# Can some mapping be open at a single point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $B$ be bilinear continuous mapping$$B:\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$$ $$(x_1,x_2;y)\mapsto (x_1y,x_2y).$$ Then $B$ is not open at $(1,1;0)$. I want to prove as follows. But I still doubt at the last sentence.

Let $U\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a neighborhood of $(1,1)$, $W\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and $V$ be a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R$, then $U\times V$ is open in $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R$.
Note that $B(1,1;0)=(0,0)$, then $$(0,0)\in B(U\times V).$$
But $B^{-1}(B(U\times V))=(\mathbb R^2\times V)\cup (W\times \mathbb R)$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R$, then $B(U\times V)$ isn't open, thus $B$ is not open at $(1,1;0)$.

Furthermore, can $B$ be continuous at a specific set? In my sense, it may be the set $\mathbb R^2\times (\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't follow the logic of your line

> But $B^{-1}(B(U\times V))=(\mathbb R^2×V)\cup (W\times\mathbb R)$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R$

Surely both $\mathbb R^2×V$ and $W\times\mathbb R$ are open subsets of $\mathbb R^3$?

---

Since you mention openness at a point, I suppose you are working with the definition

> for every $x \in X$ and every neighborhood $U$ of $x$  there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $B(x)$ such that $V\subseteq B(U)$.

If $B$ were open at $(1,1;0)$, the image of any neighborhood $U$ of $(1,1;0)$ would contain a neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Is this so? A close look at $B$ will tell you that both $x_1y$ and $x_2y$ have the same sign (if $U$ is small). Hence, the image of $U$ does not contain any point in the 2nd and 4th quadrants of the plane.

> Can $B$ be continuous at a specific set?

Your map $B$ is continuous because it's written in terms of products: you can use the limit law for products, for example.

Comment: Oh,I get it.And also I have made a printer error.I want to check whether $B$ is open at a specific set.